# php artisan migrate command not working inside my virtual machine

Tags: php, laravel

Using 172.0.0.1 output:

```
  [PDOException]                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

Using localhost output:

```
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I've tried `sudo cat /var/log/mysql/error.log` to see errors but it doesn't show anything related, just errors from a couple hours ago.

Also when I try to access my database from CLI it just outputs:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Is mysqld running?  Is your socket at /var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock?  If it's listening to port 3306, you can use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and it will use the network port instead of the socket.  Either way, you need to configure your mysql server properly with your PHP config.

Comment: Yes , mysqld is running. I don't think it has to do with config because yesterday it was working flawlessly. Should I check a service or something? Yesterday I could also access to the host with workbench, now it outputs: Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Tunnel error: Could not open port forwarding SSH channel: (2, 'Connect failed')

Comment: Using netstat, is mysql listening on port 3306?